# Applying gradient to Text only in Expo react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, gradient, linear-gradients

Its really strange that I found no solution over web for a very simple feature.
I want to add gradient to a text in expo react native project. It looks something like this

[image]

I did see a library (react-native-text-gradient) which is not updated since version 0.5x.  Linear gradient of expo creates a button and applies gradient to it.
Any solution would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248255/how-to-create-a-gradient-text-in-react-native

Comment: Well that solution works for Android but not for iOS

Answer (score 2):

Use [Masked View](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/masked-view/)

```
<MaskedView
 style={{ height: 24 }}
 maskElement={<Text style={s.text}>{children}</Text>}
>
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['cadetblue', '#fabada']}
    start={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
    end={{ x: 0, y: 0.33 }}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
  />
</MaskedView>
```