# How to make CSS instagram Text gradient Color to react native gradient color

Tags: react-native, text, gradient

background: linear-gradient(143.9deg, #515BD4 10.72%, #8134AF 30.19%, #DD2A7B 52.42%, #F58529 75.45%, #FEDA77 90.88%);

```
<MaskedView maskElement={<Text {...props} />}>
      <LinearGradient
        start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
        end={{x: 1, y: 1}}
        colors={['#515BD4', '#8134AF', '#DD2A7B', '#F58529', '#FEDA77']}
        angle={143.9}>
        <Text {...props} style={[props.style, {opacity: 0}]} />
      </LinearGradient>
    </MaskedView>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a gradient text in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248255/how-to-create-a-gradient-text-in-react-native)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.